# Property does not exist on this collection instance. (Laravel 6)

Tags: laravel

I have a for-loop that adds `<td>` rows on my table. Problem is, I cannot access the attributes of my Schedule model and it keeps giving me

> Property [date_of_shift] does not exist on this collection instance.

```
    <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
        <thead>
        <th>Employee</th>
        <!-- Format of date_of_shift field: format('Y-m-d') -->
        @for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++)
            <th>
                {{ \Carbon\Carbon::today()->addDays($i)->format('F j, Y') }}<br />
                {{ \Carbon\Carbon::today()->addDays($i)->format('D') }}
            </th>
        @endfor
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach ($employees as $employee)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $employee->user->last_name }}, {{ $employee->user->first_name }} {{ $employee->user->maiden_name }} </td>
                @for ($j = 0; $j < 7; $j++)
                    @if ( $employee->schedule->date_of_shift == \Carbon\Carbon::today()->addDays($j)->format('Y-m-d') )
                        <td>{{ $employee->schedule->time_of_shift }}</td>
                    @else
                        <td><strong>REST DAY</strong></td>
                    @endif
                @endfor
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**Employee.php**

```
public function schedule () {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Schedule');
}
```

**Schedule.php**

```
public function employee () {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Employee');
}
```

What is a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Since your relationship is `HasMany` the `$employee->schedule` returns an instance of collection so in your case the easiest thing you can do is to get `->first()` result of the collection...

```php
@if ( $employee->schedule->first()->date_of_shift == \Carbon\Carbon::today()->addDays($j)->format('Y-m-d') )
    <td>{{ $employee->schedule->first()->time_of_shift }}</td>
@else
    <td><strong>REST DAY</strong></td>
@endif
```

**OR**

Or don't change any code in your blade instead change your relation from `HasMany` to `HasOne`

```php
public function schedule () {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Schedule');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Employee.php

public function schedules () {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Schedule');
}

Schedule.php

public function employees () {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Employee');
}
```

And According to this employee can have many schedule so you cant do like

```
@if ( $employee->schedules->date_of_shift == \Carbon\Carbon::today()->addDays($j)->format('Y-m-d') )
  <td>{{ $employee->schedules->time_of_shift }}</td>
@else
```

You have to use @foreach if u want to check many schedules

You can try this

```
@foreach($employee->schedules as $schedule)
   @if ( $schedule->date_of_shift == \Carbon\Carbon::today()->addDays($j) 
        >format('Y-m-d') )
     <td>{{ $schedule->time_of_shift }}</td>
   @else
@endforeach
```

But if u want the latest one you can just utilize first() method like this

```
@if ( $employee->schedule->first()->date_of_shift == \Carbon\Carbon::today()->addDays($j) 
            >format('Y-m-d') )
   <td>{{ $employee->schedule->first()->time_of_shift }}</td>
@else
```

But in case of schedule . It belongs to one employee so you dont have to use foreach 
Thanks . Let me know if it helps

Comment: Where will the functions be placed? public function schedules () to Schedule.php or Employee.php?

Comment: Edited with details please check

Comment: I have used the foreach solution, but since its another loop, it adds extra rows than what it should.

Comment: I was thinking, that with the ```@foreach ($employees as $employee)``` loop, there could only be one iteration for ```td``` rows but it just simply adds more than what I expected when I added another ```@foreach``` loop for the schedules.